# Issue with Twilio restarting the VoiceResponse

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am using the Tiwlio SDK to create a CallResource:

```
Dim tCall = CallResource.Create(toPhone,
                                        fromPhone,
                                        url:=New Uri("http://blah.com/api-callback")
                                        )
```

The Callback returns twiml.  Once it is done recording, it never hits the Thank you section, instead starts over with the first Say.

```
Dim vr As New Twilio.TwiML.VoiceResponse()
        vr.Pause(1)
        vr.Say("Hello, please talk after the beep.", voice:="woman")
        vr.Record(trim:="trim-silence", maxLength:=10, recordingStatusCallback:=New Uri("http://blah.com/api-complete"))
        vr.Pause(10)
        vr.Say("Thank you for registering.", voice:="woman")
        vr.Hangup()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

yes, the the TwiML record verb needs an action URL, otherwise it will call the same TwiML URL, looping.

[TwiML Voice: Record (Action URL)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-action)

"Keep in mind that by default Twilio will re-request the current document's URL, which can lead to unwanted looping behavior if you're not careful. Any TwiML verbs occurring after a Record are unreachable."